# axios passes the parameter into the backend(@RequestBody), and the parameter turns out to be null

Tags: axios

Here's my front-end code:

```
// the img64 here does received data from client with a long char sequence 
console.log(img64);
axios.post(serverUrl + '/adminMng/adminFaceLogin',
    {
        username: username,
        img64: img64
    })
.then(res => {
    console.log(res.data);
    if (res.data.status == 200) {                               
        alert("Face recognition successful! Click to confirm to enter the system");
        window.location = app.adminIndexUrl;
    } else {
        alert(res.data.msg);
    }
});
```

And the AdminLoginBO is :

```
public class AdminLoginBO {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String image64;

    // getter and setter
    ...
}
```

The AdminMngControllerApi is

```
@RequestMapping("/adminMng")
public interface AdminMngControllerApi {
    @PostMapping("/adminFaceLogin")
    GraceJSONResult adminFaceLogin(@RequestBody AdminLoginBO adminLoginBO,
                                          HttpServletRequest request,
                                          HttpServletResponse response);
}
```

And the implementing class of AdinMngControllerApi is:

```
@RestController
public class AdminMngController implements AdminMngControllerApi {
     @Override
    public GraceJSONResult adminFaceLogin(AdminLoginBO adminLoginBO, HttpServletRequest request,
                                          HttpServletResponse response) {
        
        String username = adminLoginBO.getUsername(); // this value is valid, eg: "andrew"
        String image64 = adminLoginBO.getImage64(); // but this value is null
        
        //face login logics
        ...
    }
}
```

Both the params from front-end received valid value from client, but when it goes into backend, the "username" variable received the value, but the "img64" variable is null.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the name of the object sent at the front end is **img64**, and the `AdminLoginBO` expects a `image64` as a name. For the username, both of the object matches the name.

You can change `img64: img64` for `image64: img64`